# WordPress Admin - Custom link popup

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a method to have a Admin-bar custom link open in a popup.

The code I have is as follows:

```
    function mytheme_admin_bar_render() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
            $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'parent' => 'new-content',
            'id' => 'custom_link',
            'title' => __('My custom link'),
            'href' => 'http://www.google.com'
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'mytheme_admin_bar_render' );
```

Which results in:

[image]

It is still unclear to me however how I can have this specific link open (ideally) as a JavaScript popup or eventually in a new window.

Some advice would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Patrick

Comment: What is this link supposed to accomplish? Do you want it to go to a new admin page or just display some information on a popup?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply - this function should just open an outside page to display some information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `meta` information to your code will open the link in a new tab.

```
function mytheme_admin_bar_render() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
            $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'parent' => 'new-content',
            'id' => 'custom_link',
            'title' => __('My custom link'),
            'href' => __('http://www.google.com'),
            'meta'   => array(
            'target' => '_blank',),
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'mytheme_admin_bar_render' );
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Libin, your method is great thank you very much! Do you think it would be also possible to open this in a regular javascript popup? Ideally I would love this to open in a popup which size I can manually define.